# Magento is showing a "default" text in the url

Tags: url, base-url

Hello actually magento is showing me a "default" text after the base url, like this.

www.palabrainspirada.com/default/autores/

And i does not understand why is that.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled the option 'Add store code to URLs' (found in System=>Configuration=>Web). The code for the Default store is 'default' and thats why its added to the URL.